# Quadrant Queries in C gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

for the question please visit [QUESTION](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4e48b9cb8917f)
I have almost solved this quadrant queries problem of Interviewstreet using segment trees with lazy propagation but I'm getting segmentation fault. so I need someone to review my code and help me.

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
int count[4],min,max,quadrant;
};

int count[4]={0};

void set_maxmin(struct node nodes[],int n,int index,int min,int max){
int mid=(min+max)/2;
nodes[index].min=min;
nodes[index].max=max;
nodes[index].count[0]=0;
nodes[index].count[1]=0;
nodes[index].count[2]=0;
nodes[index].count[3]=0;
if(max==min+1){
    set_maxmin(nodes,n,2*index+1,min,min);
    set_maxmin(nodes,n,2*index+2,max,max);
} else if(max>min+1){
    set_maxmin(nodes,n,2*index+1,min,mid);
    set_maxmin(nodes,n,2*index+2,mid+1,max);
}
}

void tree_insert(struct node nodes[],int n,int index,int quad){
int i=0;
while(1){
    if(index<(nodes[i].max+nodes[i].min)/2){
        if(2*i+1<n) i=2*i+1;
        else break;
    } else if(index>(nodes[i].max+nodes[i].min)/2){
        if(2*i+2<n) i=2*i+2;
        else break;
    } else if(index==nodes[i].max && index!=nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+2;
    else if(index!=nodes[i].max && index==nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+1;
    else if(index!=nodes[i].max && index!=nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+1;
    else
        break;
}
nodes[i].quadrant=quad;

nodes[i].count[0]=0;
nodes[i].count[1]=0;
nodes[i].count[2]=0;
nodes[i].count[3]=0;
nodes[i].count[quad-1]++;
while(i!=0){
    i=(i-1)/2;
    nodes[i].count[quad-1]++;
}
}

void change_x(struct node nodes[],int n,int index){
int i=0,quad;
while(1){
    if(index<(nodes[i].max+nodes[i].min)/2){
        if(2*i+1<n) i=2*i+1;
        else break;
    } else if(index>(nodes[i].max+nodes[i].min)/2){
        if(2*i+2<n) i=2*i+2;
        else break;
    } else if(index==nodes[i].max && index!=nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+2;
    else if(index!=nodes[i].max && index==nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+1;
    else if(index!=nodes[i].max && index!=nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+1;
    else
        break;
}
quad=nodes[i].quadrant;
nodes[i].count[quad-1]--;
nodes[i].count[5-quad-1]++;
nodes[i].quadrant=5-nodes[i].quadrant;
while(i!=0){
    i=(i-1)/2;
    nodes[i].count[quad-1]--;
    nodes[i].count[5-quad-1]++;
}
}

void change_x_range(struct node nodes[],int n,int i,int j){
int k;
for(k=i;k<=j;k++)
    change_x(nodes,2*n-1,k);
}

void change_y(struct node nodes[],int n,int index){
int i=0,quad,quad2;
while(1){
    if(index<(nodes[i].max+nodes[i].min)/2){
        if(2*i+1<n) i=2*i+1;
        else break;
    } else if(index>(nodes[i].max+nodes[i].min)/2){
        if(2*i+2<n) i=2*i+2;
        else break;
    } else if(index==nodes[i].max && index!=nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+2;
    else if(index!=nodes[i].max && index==nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+1;
    else if(index!=nodes[i].max && index!=nodes[i].min)
        i=2*i+1;
    else
        break;
}
quad=nodes[i].quadrant;
nodes[i].count[quad-1]--;
if(quad==1 || quad==3)
    nodes[i].quadrant++;
else
    nodes[i].quadrant--;
quad2=nodes[i].quadrant;
nodes[i].count[quad2-1]++;
while(i!=0){
    i=(i-1)/2;
    nodes[i].count[quad-1]--;
    nodes[i].count[quad2-1]++;
}
}

void change_y_range(struct node nodes[],int n,int i,int j){
int k;
for(k=i;k<=j;k++)
    change_y(nodes,2*n-1,k);
}

int * count_nums(struct node nodes[],int n,int min,int max){
int i=0,*count1,*count2,*count3,k,mid;
while(1){
    mid=(nodes[i].min+nodes[i].max)/2;
    if(min==nodes[i].min && max==nodes[i].max){
        return nodes[i].count;
    } else if(min==nodes[i].min && max!=nodes[i].max){
        if(max>nodes[i].max){
            count1=nodes[i].count;
            count2=count_nums(nodes,n,nodes[i].max+1,max);
            for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                count[k]=count1[k]+count2[k];
            return count;
        } else if(2*i+1<n) i=2*i+1;
        else break;
    } else if(min!=nodes[i].min && max==nodes[i].max){
        if(min<nodes[i].min){
            count1=count_nums(nodes,n,min,nodes[i].min-1);
            count2=nodes[i].count;
            for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                count[k]=count1[k]+count2[k];
            return count;
        } else if(2*i+2<n) i=2*i+2;
        else break;
    } else if(min<=mid && max<=mid){
        if(2*i+1<n) i=2*i+1;
        else break;
    } else if(min>=mid && max>=mid){
        if(2*i+2<n) i=2*i+2;
        else break;
    } else {
        count1=count_nums(nodes,n,min,mid);
        count2=count_nums(nodes,n,mid+1,max);
        for(k=0;k<4;k++)
            count[k]=count1[k]+count2[k];
        return count;
    }
}
return count;
}

int main(){
int n,quadrant,x,y,i,q;
char k;
scanf("%d",&n);
struct node nodes[2*n-1];
set_maxmin(nodes,2*n+1,0,0,n-1);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    if(x>0 && y>0)
        tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,1);
    else if(x<0 && y>0)
        tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,2);
    else if(x<0 && y<0)
        tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,3);
    else
        tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,4);
}
scanf("%d\n",&q);
for(i=0;i<q;i++){
    scanf("%c %d %d\n",&k,&x,&y);
    if(k=='C'){
        int *temp;
        temp=count_nums(nodes,2*n-1,x-1,y-1);
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n",temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]);
    } else if(k=='X'){
        change_x_range(nodes,2*n-1,x-1,y-1);
    } else if(k=='Y'){
        change_y_range(nodes,2*n-1,x-1,y-1);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Before implementing segment trees, I got 8/11 testcases right.

Someone please help me with this

I thought I'll explain my code so that you need not try hard to understand it

set_maxmin sets max and min of all nodes 2*n-1 in number

Tree_insert inserts an element by traversing till it finds the index=max=min of a node (leaf o'course)

count_nums returns the count array of segment mentioned

change_x_range reflects the selected range along x axis and updates the count till the root

change_y_range reflects the selected range along y axis and updates the count till the root

Comment: When you receive e.g. a segmentation fault, your first reaction should be to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate where the crash occurs, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused it.

Comment: I've tried that but I'm not able to find a test case which gives seg fault. Everything seems right for my test case. So I'm more or less clueless. Please help!

Comment: 200+ lines of code is quite a lot for people here to review and diagnose when you're not sure what triggers the bug.  Does your code pass the sample data sets that they provide?

Comment: I realise that considering an array of size 2*n-1 is creating the bug. That is where it's running out of bounds. For lesser number it's working fine but the size of array shud seriously depend on whether nis odd or even. Figuring that out now. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I added a function to your code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(1);
}
```

I created a new test case with 40 points instead of 4, by adjusting the test input file and using the same 4 points 10 times.  I monitored the progress by adding tests on the input operations (using `err_exit()` to report problems).

```
int main(void)
{
    int n,x,y,i,q;
    char k;
    if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1)
        err_exit("WTF? Failed to read number of points\n");
    printf("Points: %d\n", n);
    struct node nodes[2*n-1];
    set_maxmin(nodes,2*n+1,0,0,n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d %d",&x,&y) != 2)
            err_exit("WTF? Failed to read point %d\n", i);
        printf("%d: %d %d\n", i, x, y);
        if(x>0 && y>0)
            tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,1);
        else if(x<0 && y>0)
            tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,2);
        else if(x<0 && y<0)
            tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,3);
        else
            tree_insert(nodes,2*n+1,i,4);
    }
    if (scanf("%d\n",&q) != 1)
        err_exit("WTF? Failed to read number of queries\n", q);
    printf("Queries: %d\n", n);
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%c %d %d\n",&k,&x,&y) != 3)
            err_exit("WTF? Failed to read query %d\n", i);
        printf("%d: %c %d %d\n", i, k, x, y);
        if(k=='C')
        {
            int *temp;
            temp=count_nums(nodes,2*n-1,x-1,y-1);
            printf("%d %d %d %d\n",temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]);
        }
        else if(k=='X')
            change_x_range(nodes,2*n-1,x-1,y-1);
        else if(k=='Y')
            change_y_range(nodes,2*n-1,x-1,y-1);
        else
            err_exit("WTF? %c?\n", k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code (`./tldr < input01.txt`), it produces:

```
Points: 40
0: 1 1
1: -1 1
2: -1 -1
3: 1 -1
4: 1 1
5: -1 1
6: -1 -1
7: 1 -1
8: 1 1
9: -1 1
10: -1 -1
Queries: 11
0: - 1 1
WTF? -?
```

What's happening is that you are overrunning the bounds of your array, `nodes`, and writing over the variable `n`.

You need to consider why you are using an array of `2*n-1` nodes.  There is only a need for `n` (or maybe `n + 1` nodes since the indexes in the question are 1-based, not 0-based as in C).

#### input01.txt

```
40
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
5
C 1 4
X 2 4
C 3 4
Y 1 2
C 1 3
```

Comment: n+1 is not the correct number of input. I'm building a segment tree (interval tree) [image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dJPsxzy7Sr8/UEWdteVQVtI/AAAAAAAAJoE/G1zkYJ6Jnlc/s1600/Segment+Tree.png) not a simple tree


Thanx for the function :)

Comment: OK; I think your structure is more complex than what I'd use for the same problem, but that's your affair, not mine.  You almost certainly have indexes out of control, and need to work on ensuring they are under control.  Techniques to note: (1) simple error reporting makes error checking less onerous; (2) echoing data as it is read ensures the program is seeing what you think it is seeing; (3) generating a bigger test data set by a simple technique allowed me to find a problem in your code.  All these should be standard parts of your repertoire.

Comment: I've done changes and used correct number of elements in array. every query should be O(log(N)) but it's not. It says time limit exceeded for 8 out of 11 queries and wrong answer for two. I think my implementation is correct. I don't understand why

@Jonathan Leffler: what do you mean by "I think your structure is more complex than what I'd use for the same problem". Do you have a better way? could you please hint me on that?

Comment: I only get 9/11 to pass; the other two time out.  I've created a Perl script to generate test cases; for 100000 points and 1000000 queries, my code takes about 50 seconds.  So, I don't have a way of breaking the speed barrier, yet.

Comment: I tried brute force first. 8/11 testcases passed and I wasted 2 days to code segment trees and I get 1/11 testcases passed. this sucks!